# Why [u8] does not implement Clone?

Tags: rust

The example below is just an example, I know I don't need the Clone for this to work, but if `S` were an enum with `[T]` and `Vec<T>` and I wanted to resize the vector, `T` would have to be `Clone`.

```
struct S<'a, T>{
    a: &'a [T]
}

impl<'a, T> S<'a, T> {
    pub fn borrow(&self) -> &[T] 
    where [T]: Clone {
        self.a
    }
}

fn main() {
    let slice:[u8;3] = [1,2,3]; 
    let x = S{a: &slice};
    x.borrow();
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6bbd77c6f48a2fb2e150994b3a9e1fad)

Error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `[u8]: Clone` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:17:7
   |
17 |     x.borrow();
   |       ^^^^^^ the trait `Clone` is not implemented for `[u8]`
```

So, why isn't `[u8]` `Clone`?

Comment: `[T]` is an unsized type, and hence cannot be `Clone`d (note that [`Clone::clone`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/clone/trait.Clone.html#tymethod.clone) returns `Self` but a `[T]` cannot live on the stack). A `Box<[T]>`, however, does [implement `Clone`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/clone/trait.Clone.html#impl-Clone-261) if `T: Clone` because it lives on the heap.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> So why isn't `[u8]` `Clone`?

Look at the type of the `clone` method in the definition of `Clone`:

```
pub trait Clone {
    pub fn clone(&self) -> Self;
    // more stuff omitted..
}
```

It returns `Self`, which would be `[u8]` in this case. The problem is that `[u8]` is not `Sized`, that is, since we don't know how many elements it will have we can't know its size at compile time. But returning it from this method would mean that it is moved onto the stack, which is not possible if the compiler doesn't know how much space to leave for it.

Comment: Would a possible fix be to use const generics and use a templated fixed-size array instead of a slice?

Comment: I don't really follow what you are trying to accomplish so it's hard to suggest a "fix". As you say, the example doesn't communicate the problem because `Clone` is not needed. On the surface, it looks like you need `T: Clone` not `[T]: Clone` but you didn't provide enough information to say that with any certainty.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get your code to compile by adding the `&` to the where clause:

```
impl<'a, T> S<'a, T> {
    pub fn borrow(&self) -> &[T]
    where
        &'a [T]: Clone,
    {
        self.a
    }
}
```

The key here being that the slice is the reference to a contiguous set of values: `&[u32]`.

As to why, `[u32]` does not implement `Clone`: I believe the reason is that it doesn't have any information as to how many elements are in the range of memory.  Whereas the slice type,`&[u32]`, contains a reference to the start of a series of `u32` values in memory and how many elements there are.  Without the number of elements, cloning the data would be impossible.

Comment: Note that `&'a [T]: Clone` may not lead to desired behavior, as it puts a `Clone` constraint on the _reference_ type `&[T]`. Immutable references [are always `Clone`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/clone/trait.Clone.html#impl-Clone-122) (and `Copy`) -- `&[T] : Clone` does not necessarily mean that the slice itself can be cloned.

Comment: [Example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e7d6bcffe035a4d04ab29ba10c51dcd5): Calling `self.a.clone()` in `S::borrow` does not actually clone the slice or its constituents -- it only clones the reference.

Comment: That's a very good point and good to know.